# How to make a variable to return N/A? (c language)

Tags: c

I have a code in c language and i have a function returning int value. In case of a not fullfiled condition however I need a variable from that function to give me the value N/A (not the big number which it initializes at the beginning). Any tip how to do that? Thanks a lot...

Comment: what is the value N/A supposed to be? AFAIK `int` can only be a numeric value

Comment: Return null if input is over certain value?

Comment: You can use signed -1 for `unsigned int`, `NaN` for floats and `NULL` for pointers.

Comment: @DCoder I prefer the inverse in such cases (that is, let the status be the return value).

Comment: Another option could be to have `struct retval { int value; char success; }` and then define `struct retval function(void)`.

Answer (score 6):

There is no N/A in C. The closest thing to it are value pointers. You could have a function returning a pointer to int, and return NULL in the case of an unfulfilled condition.

There are basically two possibilities, returning a pointer to static storage, or a pointer to storage allocated with malloc.

```
int *may_fail_static(int input) {
    static int result;
    if (input == 42)
         return NULL;
    else {
        result = 3 * input;
        return &result;
    }        
}

int *may_fail_malloc(int input) {
    int *result;
    if (input == 42)
        return NULL;
    else {
        result = malloc(sizeof *result);
        if (result == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        *result = 3 * input;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Both have disadvantages: The static version is not reentrant (not thread-safe). The malloc
version has significant allocation overhead and the client must explicitly free the storage after use.

That's why in C, you typically find functions of this kind:

```
/* Returns 0 on success, or -1 on failure */
int may_fail(int input, int *result) {
    if (input == 42)
        return -1;
    else {
        *result = 3 * input;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

A client may use it in the following way:

```
int x;
if (may_fail(42, &x) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: may_fail failed!\n");
    exit(1);
}
/* Answer value is now stored in x. Go ahead */
```

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways

### 1. Use a proxy value AKA [sentinel value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value)

In a case like this, easiest is if you can reserve value for N/A, which is invalid as normal return value. Common example is many library functions, which return number of bytes read/written/something, or -1 for error. If you have a known range of valid values, then define some suitable value outside of this range to mean N/A.

```
#include <limits.h>
// define NA_VALUE to be smallest possible int
#define NA_VALUE (INT_MIN)

int getInt1(const char *key) {
    if (test_if_key_exits(key)) {
        return get_int_for_key(key);
    }
    else {
        return NA_VALUE;
    }
}

void testfunc1(const char *key) {
    int value = getInt1(key);
    if (value != NA_VALUE) std::cout << value;
    else std::cout << "n/a";
}
```

### 2. Use out parameter in addition to return value

A more general alternative is to return boolean (or maybe numeric error code, or even `const char*` to error string or NULL for success), and then use pointer parameter for actual return value, like this:

```
bool getInt2(const char *key, int *result) {
    if (test_if_key_exits(key)) {
        // in case result is NULL, do not use it, just return true
        if (result) *result = get_int_for_key(key);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

void testfunc2(const char *key) {
    int value;
    if (getInt2(key, &value))std::cout << value;
    else std::cout << "n/a";
}
```

You can also reverse this, return the int as return value, and use out parameter for status. This may be useful if you want to always return some value, even a default value if nothing else, and allow an out parameter to indicate that it was a default value.

### 3. Return pointer to value, or `NULL`

Third way is to return a pointer to value, or `NULL` for NA, but you are asking about `int` return value, so this is probably not practical, there are some drawbacks. It is mostly useful in cases where you can return pointer to some existing data. This alternative, and the drawbacks, are explained in [the answer of @JoSo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19756483/1717300).

Comment: +1: The proxy value (also called sentinel value) is a good addition to my own post.

Comment: @JoSo Thanks, I think that was the word I was after, added to answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are four ways I've seen used in C libraries:

```
/*
 * return a defined unexpected value, like -1,
 * otherwise the return the result
 *
 * return -1 if failed, otherwise on success
 */
int my_function(void) {
  return -1;
}
```

---

```
/*
 * the result is stored in `ret`, and the state
 * is returned
 *
 * return -1 if failed, otherwise on success
 */
int my_function(int *ret) {
  return -1;
}
```

---

```
/*
 * the state is stored in an argument
 *
 * state = -1 if failed, otherwise on success
 */
int my_function(int *state) {
  *state = -1;
  return 0;
}
```

---

```
/*
 * with pointers and addresses
 *
 * return NULL on failed, otherwise on success
 */
int *my_function(void) {
  return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jo so. Another thing you can do -- set errno(3) to some meaning value in your function and then check its value outside.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a good idea to tamper with `errno` - this should be reserved for the runtime library.

Comment: It is solution. And yes, it is a bad solution. Probably it would be better to change design as others suggests.